# CSS Pseudo Class Inheritance

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to understand why my CSS functions in Opera, but does not in Firefox.  The effect I'm after is simply a button that, when hovered over, displays a drop down.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>

.dropcontrol {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown {
    display: none;
}

.dropcontrol:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class='dropcontrol'>TEST

    <div class='dropdown'>

        <ul>

            <li>Test 1</li>
            <li>Test 2</li>
            <li>Test 3</li>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem appears to be the `.dropcontrol:hover .dropdown`.  Any ideas as to why this would work in Opera, but not Firefox?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This code works for me as-is in FF5, IE7/8/9. What version of Firefox are you running?

Comment: Broken for me on 3.5.9.  Also happens to some coworkers, I'll have to find out what version they are using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your particular setup doesn't work, but there are better ways to go about doing it.

For starters, it's generally a better idea to do what you're doing with all lists. So you'd have something like:

```
<ul class="dropcontrol">
  <li>Test
    <ul class="dropdown">
       <li>Test 1</li>
       <li>Test 2</li>
       <li>Test 3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you have to keep `dropcontrol` as a div, then you can clean up what you have by removing the `dropdown` div and giving the ul tag the `dropdown` class.

Also, depending on what, exactly, you're trying to do, the `<select>` element may also be a better choice.

Comment: I like the HTML layout here, but the CSS is still broken.  As I mentioned above I'm using an out of date FF, but some coworkers are also having problems, so I'll have to find out what version they are on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution for firefox. I have never used Opera and I have never seen a dropdown attempted the way you have posted it. This is how I usually do it.

```
.dropcontrol {
background-color: red;
}

.dropcontrol li ul {
visibility:hidden;
}

.dropcontrol li:hover ul {
visibility:visible;
}


<div class='dropcontrol'><ul><li>TEST

    <ul>

        <li>Test 1</li>
        <li>Test 2</li>
        <li>Test 3</li>

    </ul>
</li></ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm not entirely sure why this changes the way Firefox works, but the answer was to include the doctype tag as xhtml-transitional.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/    xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: This definitely has something to do with quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with this code:

```
.dropcontrol:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

What happens if you add `.dropdown:hover`? Does that help? You may also be getting some other issues with css, try adding `!important`, that could help as well.

On another note, if your having troubles with only firefox or only Opera, you can do something like this to code css for each specific browser (may be helpful once you better know the issue)

**FireFox**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #someID {
        position: relative;
        top: -1px;
    }
}
```

**Opera**

```
@media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:10000), not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #my-id { clear:right; }
}
```

Comment: `.dropdown:hover` assumes `dropdown` is being hovered, which is impossible if it starts out hidden and isn't being revealed. Also, -1 for jumping to hacks.